# Multi page viewPager2 with paging 3 doesn't show data on page 2 using SharedViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, paging

I want to implement two view tab, with recycle view as list, and using paging 3 for collecting data and return will be kotlin flow. everthing is working perfectly at tab one, but **nothing show** in tab two.

the viewModel code (SharedViewModel):

```kotlin
@ExperimentalPagingApi
@HiltViewModel
class MovieViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MovieRepository,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {
    private val TAG = "MovieVM"


    private var _moviePaging: Flow<PagingData<MovieEntities>>? =
        repository.getMovie().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    private var _tvPaging: Flow<PagingData<MovieEntities>>? =
        repository.getTv().cachedIn(viewModelScope)



    init {
        loadMovie()
    }

    // new paging
    var moviePaging = MutableStateFlow<PagingData<MovieEntities>>(PagingData.empty())
    var tvPaging = MutableStateFlow<PagingData<MovieEntities>>(PagingData.empty())

    private fun loadMovie() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _moviePaging?.collectLatest {
                moviePaging.value = it
            }
            _tvPaging?.collectLatest {
                tvPaging.value = it
            }
        }
    }
```

the code is run. when i am debuging, only `_moviePaging` is call and show logger retrofit GET, but the `_tvPaging` is nothing, not call api, like never triggered to run (unreachable?)

so, i was change order, call `_tvPaging` first. then only `_tvPaging` is run.

I want two line of code `_moviePaging` and `_tvPaging` running, but now is just one of them. Please Help.

Any response will apreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading some documentation, and understand about work flow coroutine,

> one coroutine scope for hot flow only one methode can run, they suspend forever

so, the solution is make `viewModelScope` for each hot flow

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _moviePaging?.collectLatest {
                moviePaging.value = it
            }
        }
viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _tvPaging?.collectLatest {
                tvPaging.value = it
            }
        }
```